# File cannot be found - suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, file-not-found, imread

I am iterating through files in a directory and subdirectory and doing a function on each image. 
It has suddenly stopped working and cannot find the files

I am using the full path name, and have checked all spellings are correct.

```
from pathlib import Path

Path = '/Users/.../images_for_python/'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(Path):
    for face_image in f:
        if face_image.endswith("g"): 

            img = io.imread(face_image) 
            dets = detector(img)
```

Error comes at the line "img= io.imread(face_image)"
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '100_F23_Neutral.jpg'

Surely the file has been found as I didn't specify the file name?
Would really appreciate some help as I am sure it is just a silly mistake!

Comment: is that error returned the first time through the `for` loop? its looking for the file in the directory the script is called from not the directory that holds the files.

Comment: easiest way to fix is to just move the .py file to the directory holding the files you want to work with. alternatively you can use the `os` package to work with file paths.